# How does one solve $ y' = ( {2+\sqrt x})/({2+\sqrt y})$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How does one solve $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2+\sqrt x}{2+\sqrt y}$? I tried moving $x$ equation to left side and $y$ equation to the right side, but that results in $\displaystyle2y+\frac{2}{3}y^{\frac{3}{2}}$ which is really hard to solve into $y$.

Answer (score 2):

$$(2+\sqrt{y})dy=(2+\sqrt{x})dx$$
$$\Longrightarrow 2y+\dfrac{2}{3}y^{\frac{3}{2}}=2x+\dfrac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$$

let $y=u^2$,then
$$\dfrac{2}{3}u^3+2u^2-2x-\dfrac{2}{3}x^{\dfrac{3}{2}}-C=0$$
$$u^3+3u^2-p=0$$
where
$$p=\dfrac{3}{2}(2x+\dfrac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}-C)$$

and you can see this cubic equation Cardano's method

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what has to happen:

$$(2+\sqrt{y}) dy = (2+\sqrt{x}) dx \implies 2 y+\frac{2}{3} y^{\frac32} = 2 x+\frac{2}{3} x^{\frac32}+2C$$

where $C$ is an integration constant.

By subtracting $y$ on both sides and squaring, we get a cubic equation for $y$ as a function of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Every ODE which is of form: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{f(x)}{g(y)}$$ is a seperable one and can be solved easily: $$\int g(y)dy-\int f(x)dx=C$$

Comment: It's worth noting that if you read the question, the asked is aware of this fact. Their problem is that after doing this, they have a difficult time solving for $y$ as a function of $x$.